# SED: Multiple sed statements combined in one

Tags: sed

I am replacing multiple patterns in a sed statement on linux but am running into an error.
I have saved this line of code in script.sh and am running it like bash script.sh

```
script.sh
sed "/#/d; s//my/path/to/folder//g; s/.my.file.extension.gz -//g; s/:/\t/g" < output_file.txt > cleaned_output.tsv
     
/#/d: delete rows containing #
s//my/path/to/folder//g: replace path with nothing
s/.my.file.extension.gz -//g:  replace file extension and some additional character with nothing
s/:/\t/g: replace : with tab

Error
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: `s//my/path/to/folder//g` looks like a bad idea. Use something else than `/` as a `sed` delimiter. Perhaps `sed 's,/my/path/to/folder,,g'` would do the work

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 84: unterminated `s' command

Comment: akang: That's not an error you'd get from the line I proposed though

Comment: I am running an entire line with the change you suggested sed -i '/#/d; s,/my/path/to/folder,,g; s,.my.file.extension.gz -/,g'

Comment: The line in your question _with_ my replacements would be `sed '/#/d;s,/my/path/to/folder,,g;s/.my.file.extension.gz -//g;s/:/\t/g'` - Note the _two_ `,` before `g`.  It's a bit hard to tell if you'd want the last `/` in the path removed too though so you may want `sed '/#/d;s,/my/path/to/folder/,,g;s/.my.file.extension.gz -//g;s/:/\t/g'`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using something else than `/` when you've got a lot of `/` in that what you want to replace. Example with `,`:

```
sed '/#/d;s,/my/path/to/folder,,g;s/.my.file.extension.gz -//g;s/:/\t/g'
```

or, if you want the last `/` in the path removed too:

```
sed '/#/d;s,/my/path/to/folder/,,g;s/.my.file.extension.gz -//g;s/:/\t/g'
```